# What happens to result cache data when the actual data changes?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, sql-tuning

If I executed a query and its result is stored in the result cache, when I modify one of the tables used in my code, by an insert, delete, update, etc, what happens to the data in the result cache?

Does it deleted completely and in the next execution it read all from the disc? Or does it stay but when the next query executed the changed area are read from the disc and merged?

So basically, what happens to the data in the result cache when one of the table data changed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what happens to the data in the result cache when one of the table data changed

Oracle invalidates the cached result set immediately. The next query which would have used the cache queries the database and re-populates the cache.